# I am trying to deploy node api on nginx server, i didnt find any results,but i have already deployed angular api on nginx server and it is working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

[In first picture I uploded angular api dist file in nginx html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxsob.png)

[Now where i want to upload node api in nginx server?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Z2H.png)

Comment: In above pictures, i uploaded angular api dist file in html files.

Comment: Please do not post your code in images!